# adding List values to a dictionary

Tags: c#, idictionary, oledbdatareader

I am trying to populate a dictionary of which the subject value which is unique have various Code values that should be matched with it.

```
CODE    SUBJECT

7DIM-062  Recruitment and Selection

7DIM-063    Recruitment and Selection

7DIM-064    Recruitment and Selection

7DIM-065    Recruitment and Selection

7DIM-066    Recruitment and Selection

7DIM-067    Recruitment and Selection

7DIM-068    Recruitment and Selection
```

So what I want is only for Reqruitment and Selection to be added to the Dictionary once as the unique key and then all the corresponding codes to be added to a List.
How would I go about in doing this?

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
```

this is my query

```
OleDbDataReader dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dbReader.Read())
{
    string code = (string)dbReader["CODE"];
    string subject = (string)dbReader["SUBJECT"];
    //???? this is the point where I would want to add the values
    dict.Add(subject, new List<string>().Add(code);
```

Comment: Consider a Lookup, which is essentially a dictionary with multiple values for each key.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Duplicate keys? I'm not sure about the implementation details inside Lookup, but it does exactly what you're saying: For each distinct subject, it would return a grouping of the codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) to look if your dictionary already contains that subject. Then you can add the new code to it, otherwise add subject+code:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
while (dbReader.Read())
{
    string code = (string)dbReader["CODE"];
    string subject = (string)dbReader["SUBJECT"];

    List<string> codes;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(subject, out codes))
    {
        codes.Add(code);
    }
    else
    {
        codes = new List<string>() { code };
        dict.Add(subject, codes);
    }
}
```

It's just more efficient than to lookup twice.

> This method combines the functionality of the ContainsKey method and
>   the Item property. If the key is not found, then the value parameter
>   gets the appropriate default value for the type TValue; for example, 0
>   (zero) for integer types, false for Boolean types, and null for
>   reference types. Use the TryGetValue method if your code frequently
>   attempts to access keys that are not in the dictionary. Using this
>   method is more efficient than catching the KeyNotFoundException thrown
>   by the Item property. This method approaches an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 5):

First check if your dictionary already has the key, if not add new key with `List` initialization.

```
if (!dict.ContainsKey(subject))
{
    dict[subject] = new List<string>();    
}

dict[subject].Add(code);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Lookup`<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var subjects = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
while (dbReader.Read())
{
    string code = (string)dbReader["CODE"];
    string subject = (string)dbReader["SUBJECT"];

    subjects.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(subject, code));
}
// ...
var lookup = subjects.ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
var recruitmentAndSelectionCodes = lookup["Recruitment and Selection"].ToList();
// returns
//     7DIM-062 
//     7DIM-063 
//     etc.
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, OP states that subject is unique, but I don't see how it affects my answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: but the code above does exactly this, doesn't it?